# How to get unique android device identifier using browser?

Tags: android, browser, uniqueidentifier

What i can use as an unchanging unique identifier for android devices, accessible through a browser?

Comment: I don't think android will let you do that (I hope). That's a privacy issue, if you can track the users phone you are violating his privacy. The most you could do (or should) is to use a cookie, but the user will (should) have the capability to erase it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the useragent of the browser, though it can be changed by the user, so it's not really unchanging.

Otherwise, if you have a native Android app behind your code, there are some classes to get specific data about the phone (Manufacturer, Id, ...)